# Make iOS / Android HTTP request looks like it comes from PC Browser?

Tags: android, ios, http

Is it possible to make HTTP request from iOS / Android Application to look for the Server exactly the same as if it came from PC Browser?

So, it would be impossible for the Server to detect that it is not actually from PC but from Mobile.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking. #unclear , do you want to detect from what pc or mobile http request is hitting to server ?

Comment: you can try setting custom headers which mimic the headers sent from a PC

Comment: I want to trick server into thinking that request came from PC

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can alter the User Agent header to make it look like the request was made by f.ex Internet Explorer.

Here is some clues on how to accomplish this on Android:

[Android HTTP User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent)

iOS:

[Change User-Agent and remove App Name and defaults iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297596/change-user-agent-and-remove-app-name-and-defaults-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Set the user agent on the request to other than the default to fool the server into thinking the request is coming from other than a device. One list of user agents is at http://www.useragentstring.com.